# Add Polylines From An Array With A Space

Tags: android

I've created this loop that draw the polylines that i need on google maps v2. 
Every loop it should draw one polyline between two markers.
But the problem is that it connect between the new polyline and the last polyline .
how can i remove this "Polyline connector" ?

This is my code:

```
for(int i=0;i<cons;i++){


                int a=i+1;
                   int b=i+2;
                   int c=i+3;
                   String k0=prefs.getString("cons"+i, "defValue");
                   String k1=prefs.getString("cons"+a, "defValue");
                   String k2=prefs.getString("cons"+b, "defValue");
                   String k3=prefs.getString("cons"+c, "defValue");

                   LatLng constpoint= new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(k0),Double.parseDouble(k1));

                   markerOptions.position(constpoint);                 
                googleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);

                LatLng constpoint2=new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(k2),Double.parseDouble(k3));
                 markerOptions.position(constpoint2);                  
                    googleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);


                       // Adding the polyline to the map
                      // googleMap.addPolyline(polylineOptions);
                       line2= googleMap.addPolyline(polylineOptions
                          .add(constpoint,
                                 constpoint2));

                       i=i+3;
               }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved.

Every time you start the loop just create a new PolylineOptions like this:

```
 line2= googleMap.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions()
                          .add(constpoint,
                                 constpoint2));
```